# How complex a project should be to add to LinkedIn accomplishments?

Tags: resume, linkedin, projects

I want to add a project I did, to LinkedIn. This is an ongoing project, and I completed some initial part of it, which involves one Python program (calling multiple functionalities from multiple packages like sklearn, OpenCV etc). I have been working on it since 2 months. Can I add it to LinkedIn?

Also, I am doing some coding like, building a recommendation system, tool to identify gestures etc., for learning purpose. Is it appropriate to add them as projects in LinkedIn?
Or if there is a better and more appropriate way to showcase my work to public, could you please suggest?

Comment: Are you building these things as a part of a job? Or are you self-employed? Or a student?

Comment: @morsor: I am a student.

Answer (score 4):

You can put anything you want on LinkedIn that doesn't violate their terms. There are no rules. I have looked up some people I knows profiles and many of them resemble a beautiful fairytale fantasy in comparison to their actual expertise and accomplishments.

Comment: Not as a rule, I am asking how is the usual reasonable practice? E.g. if I add too many trivial works there, then importance of a good work can get unnoticed. Similarly if I add only complex projects, then a medium good project doesn't get a chance to get noticed. I am giving links to the source code there, so it will not be a fairy tale for me. But trying to understand how complex projects should be added there, and how best to showcase the smaller works.

Comment: There is no best way. Look at other peoples profiles and see if any of the styles suit you is your best option.

Comment: @SuktiSen What is difficult for you may be trivial for others. Just keep adding whatever projects you are doing as it reflects your current skill level. And as you grow more experienced, you will yourself remove old projects that will look "silly" to you as you keep adding more advanced projects.

Comment: As sfxedit says, what you list depends on what you have to show off. If all you've done are minor projects, then list them because you need to show some achievements. If you have big achievements, then put minor things at the bottom or leave them out.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, put something that is in line with your level of experience: in the same way as running the 100 meters in 15 seconds can be a good time for a high schooler who just started field track, while not being a good time for an athlete in their prime with 8 years of field track under their soles, you want your accomplishments to highlight your capabilities.

Comment: 15 seconds for 100 meters would not be good time even in junior high school :P

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, I listed non-professional activities - so I would recommend doing so, but tweaking it towards what is likely to interest hiring managers:

1. What was your role? Alone or part of a team?
2. Was the task ordered by someone else or yourself?
3. Did you complete the task on-time?
4. Which skills or tools did you learn or improve?

Finally, a concise introduction clearly stating your initial career goals could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already covered the "complexity" question and I generally agree: Include the projects that are in line with your experience.  If there are some you're particularly proud of from earlier in your career that you would like to keep, make sure you indicate the time period you worked on these projects so it's understood that you have advanced since then.

An additional bit of advice that would apply also to your resume/CV, that also applies to artists' portfolios:  If you're trying to limit the number of projects on the list, focus on the ones with the ones that represent **the kind of things you would like to do more of**.